# How to permanent redirect from second level domain to top level domain using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Recently, top level domains were enabled in my region. So, I want to redirect all traffic from my old domain: site.com.ex to site.ex

I've tried a bunch of .htaccess magic but no dice. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I just got around to it and it seems to work well in all cases:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com\.ex [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ex/$1 [R=301,L]
```